# MySQL Where Clause Using with 2 LeftJoins (3 tables) ERROR

Tags: mysql, join, syntax-error, left-join, where-clause

When I used 2 tables with one join, everything was fine, but after i had to make another join:

```
SELECT logins.user as luser, rozliczenia.godziny as godziny, rozliczenia.stawka as stawka, rozliczenia.premia as premia, rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna, SUM(sprzedane.liczba) as liczbasprz
FROM logins
LEFT JOIN rozliczenia
ON logins.id=rozliczenia.userid
AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm')
LEFT JOIN sprzedane
ON logins.user=sprzedane.user AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00')
WHERE luser!='SUPERUSER' AND luser!='agata' AND luser!='tomek'
```

everythink screwed up :( Any thoughts why?

Here's the error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'WHERE luser!='SUPERUSER' AND luser!='agata' AND luser!='tomek'' at line 1
```

**EDIT**

Here's the whole code without variables

```
SELECT logins.user as luser, rozliczenia.godziny as godziny, rozliczenia.stawka as stawka, rozliczenia.premia as premia, rozliczenia.premiainna as premiainna, SUM(sprzedane.liczba) as liczbasprz
FROM logins LEFT JOIN rozliczenia
ON logins.id=rozliczenia.userid AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('2015-1-00') AND DATE('2015-1-31')
LEFT JOIN sprzedane
ON logins.user=sprzedane.user AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('2015-1-00')
WHERE luser!='SUPERUSER' AND luser!='agata' AND luser!='tomek'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
ON logins.user=sprzedane.user AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00')
```

Should read:

```
ON logins.user=sprzedane.user AND somedate BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE(rozliczenia.data)
```

Comment: Hah, i guess though i scanned code several times for syntax error i didn't see that :) thanks, fresh eye of someone else always helps

Comment: Code blindness: A pretty common disease for all developers :)

Answer (score 0):

Error is on second last line

```
AND DATE(rozliczenia.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00')
```

Correct syntax for `BETWEEN` is

```
BETWEEN date1 AND date2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple errors.  I think the query should look more like this:

```
SELECT l.user as luser, r.godziny, r.stawka, r.premia,
       r. premiainna, SUM(s.liczba) as liczbasprz
FROM logins l LEFT JOIN
     rozliczenia r
     ON l.id  = r.userid AND
        DATE(r.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm') LEFT JOIN
     sprzedane s
     ON l.user = s.user AND
        DATE(r.data) BETWEEN DATE('$rok-$mies-00') AND DATE('$rok-$mies-$daysinm') -- The AND part is a guess
WHERE l.user NOT IN ('SUPERUSER', 'agata', 'tomek')
GROUP BY l.user;
```

Notes:

- You do not need `as` when you are not changing the column name.
- Table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.
- Use `NOT IN` for a list of values.
- Ultimately, you need `GROUP BY` for the aggregation (unless you only want one row).
- You cannot use a column aliases defined in the `SELECT` in the `WHERE`.
- You should use parameterized queries instead of string substitution (although I haven't made that change).

Comment: thanks for NOT IN part, but the problem was just a syntax error ;)

Comment: and it's logins.user as luser, and not l.user as luser

Comment: @MateuszSowiński . . . The tables have aliases so the query is easier to write and to read.

Comment: and i use aliases for columns use them easier in php